# Rstudio: how to create a popup window for credential when using open_connection?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I currently use the following to create a connection to a server. however, I have to put my username and passwords into that code. I remember there is a way to create a connection where a window would pop up and you enter your credential. this way, I dont reveal my details if I accidentally share the codes with someone else. How can I do that?

```
open_connection(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xx',port=5119,user="<username>:<password>")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use the [`rstudioapi`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rstudioapi/) package.

You should use the [`showPrompt()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rstudioapi/topics/showPrompt) function to get data that is able to be displayed; ie. is not confidential (usernames, etc).

Then, use the [`askForPassword()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rstudioapi/topics/askForPassword) function to get the confidential information (passwords, etc).

Word of warning here! You should **never** save passwords in the memory or as variables or as part of the global options. So be careful.

Nonetheless, the functionality still exists. So here's how you can do it:

```r
# Get packages
library(rstudioapi)

# First, get the connection
conn <- showPrompt(title="Connection", message="Input connection:", default="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx")

# Second, get the port
port <- showPrompt(title="Port", message="Input port:", default="5119")

# Third, get the username
user <- showPrompt(title="Username", message="Input username:", default="")

# Fourth, get the password, anonymously
pass <- askForPassword(prompt="Input password:")

# Now, pull it all together
open_connection(host=host, port=port, user=paste0("<",user,">:<",pass,">"))

# Lastly, delete everything from memory
remove(conn, port, user, pass)
```

To be really risk-averse, it'd be better to place everything within a function. Because that way, the variables are definitely not saved to memory. You can implement it like this:

```r
open_conn <- function(conn=NA, port=NA, user=NA, pass=NA) {
    require(rstudioapi)
    if (is.na(conn)) {
        conn <- showPrompt(title="Connection", message="Input connection:", default="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx")
    }
    if (is.na(port)) {
        port <- showPrompt(title="Port", message="Input port:", default="5119")
    }
    if (is.na(user)) {
        user <- showPrompt(title="Username", message="Input username:", default="")
    }
    if (is.na(pass)) {
        pass <- askForPassword(prompt="Input password:")
    }
    tryCatch(
        {
            open_connection(host=host, port=port, user=paste0("<",user,">:<",pass,">"))
        },
        error=function(cond) {
            return(FALSE)
        }
    )
    return(TRUE)
}

open_conn()
```

(Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r#answer-12195574) for properly formatting a `tryCatch()` function)

Finally, I don't know what package you used for running the `open_connection()` function... I assume it's from the the rkdb package ([`rkdb::open_connection()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rkdb/topics/open_connection)), but since you didn't include the `library()` command, I can't be sure.

If you wanted to see these functions in action, this is a good example of code where these functions have been implemented when automating certain git processes: [`get_Credentials()`](https://github.com/chrimaho/VanillaNeuralNetworksInR/blob/8ffb759224b5e7cee9a335924a83d6d9ba81891e/AutomateGit.R#L48).